# .htaccess URL Argument Rewriting to NGINX

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

We are moving a PHP site from Apache to NGINX and came up against a problem when trying to get NGINX to recognize arguments passed from site URLs into index.php.

Our .htaccess command on Apache looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)[/]?$   /index.php?market=$1&area=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

This rule allows index.php understand that $market comes from the first URL parameter, $area comes from the second and $id comes from the third.

So, www.domain.com/miami/profiles/100 provides index.php with $market = miami, $area = profiles and $id = 100.

We've tried a variety of failed solutions hoping to achieve the same thing in the site's NGINX conf file. Here are a few we've tried that don't work:

```
location /sitename {
    root /www/sitename;
    try_files $uri /sitename/index.php?market=$args&area=$args&id=$args;
}


location /sitename {
    root /www/sitename;
    try_files $uri /sitename/index.php/?market=$args?area=$args?id=$args;
}



location /sitename {
    rewrite "^/index.php/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]{3})$"
    /index.php?market=$1&area=$2&id=$3 last;    
}
```

Can anyone spot what we are doing wrong here and show us the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You try to access the site like this: "www.domain.com/miami/profiles/100" but in your rewrite rule you specify that the request URL must contain "index.php", so you should access it like this: "www.domain.com/index.php/miami/profiles/100". Or modify your regex a bit so it looks cleaner:

```
location /sitename {
    rewrite "^/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]{3})$"
    /index.php?market=$1&area=$2&id=$3 last;    
}
```

Now you can access the website the way you wanted:
www.domain.com/miami/profiles/100

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I put in your revised rewrite and still did not get the behavior that I was looking for.

Comment: I wrote a new method of getting URL variables into index.php. So, now I define the $market, $area, and $id variables from an array created from the server_URI. Here is the code for that:

Comment: $url_parts = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if(isset($url_parts['1'])) {
 
 $market = $url_parts['1'];

}

if(isset($url_parts['2'])) {
 
 $area = $url_parts['2'];

}

if(isset($url_parts['3'])) {

 $id = $url_parts['3'];
 
}

Comment: Then I found and copied in the following rewrite commands into the nginx conf file for the site:

Comment: location / {
            
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }
 
        location @rewrite {
                # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
                # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
        }

Comment: The combination of these two modifications seems to have gotten things working though I need to do further testing before being 100% on the solution. I do wish I understood more of what is going in the new conf file location conditionals as currently, I do not fully understand what is happening there.